# Is this an example of a closure in C#?

Tags: c#, closures

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = 3;

    Func<int, Func<int>> func = 
        x => () =>
    {
        return x;
    };

    var result1 = func(s);

    func = null;

    s = 5;

    var result2 = result1();

    Console.WriteLine(result2);


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

My understanding is that x is not actually declared as a variable eg. var x = 3. Instead, it's passed into the outer function, which returns a function that returns the original value. At the time it is returning this, it creates a closure around x to remember its value. Then later on, if you alter s, it has no effect.

Is this right?

(Output is 3 by the way, which I'd expect).

Edit: here's a diagram as to why I think it is

[image: Closure example]

x=3 is passed into the func, and it returns a function that simply returns x. But x doesn't exist in the inner function, only its parent, and its parent no longer exists after I make it null. Where is x stored, when the inner function is ran? It must create a closure from the parent.

Further clarification:

```
    int s = 0;

    Func<int, Func<int>> func = 
        x => () =>
    {
        return x;
    };

    for (s = 0; s < 5; s++)
    {
        var result1 = func(s);

        var result2 = result1();

        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    };
```

Output is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

However with your example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int s = 0;

    Func<int, Func<int>> func = 
        x => () =>
    {
        return s;
    };

    List<Func<int>> results = new List<Func<int>>();

    for (s = 0; s < 5; s++)
    {
         results.Add(func(s));
    };

    foreach (var b in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b());
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The output is 5 5 5 5 5, which isn't what you want. It hasn't captured the value of the variable, it's merely retained a reference to the original s.

Closures are created in javascript precisely to avoid this problem.

Comment: `Func<int, Func<int>> func = x => () => x + s;` would close over `s`

Comment: Actually, who's to say that the later isn't what they want?  It's the power (and danger) of closures.  You are closing on s, and then modifying s before it's invoked.

Comment: Also your last example doesn't make sense, you're passing in `s` but also closing on `s` in the lambda itself (the `return s` clause), leaving `x` unused...

Comment: You're right on both counts, of course. In many cases, I bet it is what they want. Correct, `x` is unused in the 2nd example (I just didn't bother removing it). I might post a follow up question asking why in the 01234 example, the output is not also 55555, because it's storing `x` somewhere, but strangely not as a reference to `s`. It's probably just as simple as it's storing it unboxed, and so it reverts to a value type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not a closure on `s`, `x` is just an argument to the lambda expression which generates a delegate (which could actually be simplified to `x => () => x`.

```
        Func<int, Func<int>> func = x => () => x;

        var a = func(3);

        var b = func(5);

        Console.WriteLine(a());
        Console.WriteLine(b());
```

You'll get `3` and `5` as expected.  In neither case does it actually remember `x` from the other time, but it *does* close on `x` locally during the duration of the outer lambda.

Basically, each call to `x => () => x` will create a new `() => x` delegate which captures the local value of `x` (not of the `s` passed in).

Even if you use `s` and pass it in, and change it, you still get `3` and `5`:

```
        int s = 3;
        Func<int, Func<int>> func = x => () => x;

        var a = func(s);

        s = 5;

        var b = func(s);

        // 3 and 5 as expected
        Console.WriteLine(a());
        Console.WriteLine(b());
```

Now, it *does* capture on the local variable `x` *within* the local function, which is generated at *every* call.  So the `x` won't persist between invocations of the larger lambda, but it will be captured if changed later in the lambda.

For example, let's say instead you had this:

```
        int s = 3;
        Func<int, Func<int>> func = x => 
            () => {
                      Func<int> result = () => x;
                      x = 10 * x;
                      return result;
                   };

        var a = func(s);

        s = 5;

        var b = func(s);
```

In this case, the closure on `x` within the anonymous method is more obvious.  The results of running this will be 30 and 50 because modifications to `x` within the anonymous method affect the closure on the `x` local to that anonymous method, however, these do not carry over between calls, because it's only capturing the local `x` passed into the anonymous method, and not the `s` used to call it.

So, to sum up, in your diagram and example:
* **main** passes `s` into the larger lambda (**func** in your diagram)
* **func** closes on `x` at the time it's called to generate the anonymous method `() => x`

Once the call to the outer lambda is made (func) the closer begins and ends because it's local to that lambda only and doesn't close on anything from main.

Does that help?

Comment: There are three tiers of scope, the Main function, the 'func' function, and the returned function. X isn't stored anywhere, it's passed into the 'func' function, and stored there in a closure, such that when the inner function of `return x;` is called, it must ask its immediate parent for the value (3), which the parent stored in a closure, even though the parent has been made null. Or so I think.

Comment: s is not in the scope of the function in the same way that in my example x is not in the scope of the inner function. The difference is, in my example, C# stores the value of x itself for later by creating a closure (somewhere, it stores x=3 for later use). In your example, the s is not stored and in fact if it is changed before your enumerable.range is evaluated, the results will change too.

Comment: @SLC: more updates to show changing the values with your function and `x`, also, in my example `s` is a closure, and thus changing it does have an effect if changed before ran.

Comment: Correct, that's the behaviour I would expect with a closure, because it has captured x and if 'x' changes later on, it doesn't affect it. You'd use a closure in javascript precisely because if you used your first example, you'd get errornous results later on. I'll update my question to demonstrate how.

Comment: @SLC: Added another example, perhaps this will clear things up a bit?

Comment: @SLC: The key point seems to be tripping you up was pointed out by Jesse in another comment. A closure "captures the _variable_, not the _value_."

Comment: There are two things though, one is that an integer is a value type, and two, shouldn't it capture the variable at that time, and it should not be possible to change it later?

Comment: I understand your examples, I think we need to discuss semantics instead. My understanding of a closure is C# giving you access to variables outside of your scope, as seen by your initial concise enumerable example, where s is accessible even though it is not part of the function. I've never used closures in C#, this is my first time, I only have experience from Javascript where I used them to avoid the 5 5 5 5 5 problem I illustrated, because you don't want it to reference the current s, you want it to make a copy of it (that is the point, I thought), so you get the expected result.

Comment: In addition with s being a value type, I am confused as to why it behaves like a reference. (Lastly, I notice you said this isn't a closure on s, I agree - I was wondering if it was a closure on x I guess, to be specific)

Comment: @slc: Because a closure captures the variable itself, it doesn't just copy the value, or it would be no differ.than a plain argument.

Comment: This is perhaps just a javascript thing then. You have a function within a function to create a new scope and preserve the value. You have to do this to avoid the 5555 problem which occurs if you create functions that alert 'x' and set them up in a for loop. They will all end up alerting the last known value of x, even if they were passed in x=1, x=2, etc. as you see above with s. This is what separated creating a closure from passing in an argument, I thought.

Comment: if you define `results` out of scope, you still end up with 55555 so it still keeps the reference to s even when the scope is gone. This seems to contradict that it retains a reference to s - it must also retain `s` itself somewhere.

Comment: @SLC: it sounds like there are differences between how javascript and .NET create closures.

Comment: I'm thinking that your example is a closure on s, and mine is a closure on x, but in your case, s is still floating around out there, and you can change it if you have a reference to it anywhere in the code and the function will reflect that. In my example using x, somehow the reference is lost - when it calls the inner function, it remembers x for the future, but x isn't a reference to s. So I need to figure out why that happens. Cheers for your help it's been very enlightening!

Comment: @SLC: It can certainly be crazy at times, fortunately there are code assist tools (ReSharper, etc) that will warn you if you're modifying over a closure so you can examine if that's really what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 4):

No, change

```
Func<int, Func<int>> func = 
    x => () =>
{
    return x;
};
```

to

```
Func<int, Func<int>> func = 
    x => () =>
{
    return s;
};
```

and it *closes* over the `s` variable.

Comment: In this case, modifying s should not affect the return value, but it does... it outputs 5 instead of 3 which I would not expect.

Comment: It's perfectly expected as it captures the *variable*, not the *value*.

Comment: Isn't the idea for the variable to remain in the scope it was passed in as?

Comment: Nope. Lambdas capture variables.